# Windows incompletely shuts down after heavy use

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, shutdown, hp-pavilion

My HP Pavilion 15 Laptop (came with Windows 8 and upgraded to 8.1 and now on Insider Preview) has a Shutdown problem.

It'll shutdown completely without any issue if it used for a short while. But there is an issue if I use it for some longer time with heavy use (like Visual Studio).

It closes all apps and shuts down to some level. Power LED and Wireless LED are still on (Wireless LED indicates Wireless is turned off). Processor fan still runs.

In this situation, I can't shutdown further or turn on the Laptop. I have to use the Power Button to force shutdown.

Comment: This sounds liike a driver issue.  Have you verified all your drivers are Windows 10 compatiable.  Is using a stable build of Windows 10 a possability to rule out the problem is caused by the instable Insider Preview build?

Comment: @Ramhound All drivers are automatically installed by Windows. This error also occurred on Windows 10 Anniversary Update (It's a stable version)

Comment: Which model of HP Pavilion 15 is it? Also, are there any error messages in the Event Viewer?

Comment: @CharlieRB It is **n005TX**. I couldn't find any error in Event Viewer regarding this.

Comment: There was a [BIOS update in July of 2016 (F.70 Rev.A)](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/HP-Pavilion-15-n000-Notebook-PC-series/5401225/model/5422981/swItemId/ob-170723-1). Has that been installed? That will sometimes help with these issues. Also, you might want to run diagnostics to verify hardware is functioning properly and eliminate it as suspect. After that, Windows troubleshooting...

Comment: "All drivers are automatically installed by Windows." - This is not guarantee your getting the best driver for the device, many times, the drivers distributed on this channel are outdated, have you looked at updating them manually?

Answer (score 1):

Check the temperature of your CPU, probably a problem to evacuate the heat. The BIOS have a security maximum heat, if the temperature came over, the computer shut down. Clean your fan properly and make a new try. You can find software to monitor the heat something like [Real Temp](https://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/)

Comment: RealTemp shows the temperature is OK. And few days ago I cleaned the Processor fan.

Comment: For now, the tempereture is okay but you need to check the temperature before the shutdown, try to make it higher with a heavy use (with your Visual Studio open).

Comment: Else can be a memory issue, maybe bad sector? http://superuser.com/questions/452606/a-ram-stick-has-a-few-bad-blocks-is-there-any-way-i-can-turn-them-off-or-alloc

Comment: If the issue is regarding the temperature, then it should be shut down after cooling it. One day I put it over a night to check and it was still on the same condition at the morning.
I ran memory check and found no errors. And I replaced the HDD a week ago.